# JavaScript 'var' Data/Object Sizes

Tags: javascript, variables, memory-management, size

Does JavaScript optimize the size of variables stored in memory?  For instance, will a variable that has a boolean value take up less space than one that has an integer value?

Basically, will the following array:

```
var array = new Array(8192);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  array[i] = true;
```

be any smaller in the computer's memory than:

```
var array = new Array(8192);
far (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  array[i] = 9;
```

Comment: That depends on the JS implementation (I guess no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Boolean's generally (and it will depend on the user agent and implementation) will take up 4 bytes, while integer's will take up 8.

Check out this other StackOverflow question to see how some others managed to measure memory footprints in JS: [JavaScript object size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size)

Edit: Section 8.5 of the ECMAScript Spec states the following:

> The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 values, representing the doubleprecision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values as specified in the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic

... so all numbers should, regardless of implementation, be 8 bytes.

Comment: @RobW, I can't remember where I came across this originally... it was lying in the back of my brain somewhere but I've added a reference that seems to agree with the back of my brain.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1248473/1048572) should lead you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Well, js has only one number type, which is a 64-bit float. Each character in a string is 16 bits ( src: douglas crockford's , javascript the good parts ). Handling of bools is probably thus interpreter implementation specific. if I remember correctly though, the V8 engine surely handles the 'Boolean' object as a 'c bool'.

Comment: What's a C bool? C doesn't have a boolean type. Also, V8 is written in C++.

Comment: yeah that was a typo. I meant cpp bool. Good catch. But in terms of memory, they are absolutely the same, wherein when I say 'c bool', i mean its a char which is 8 bits.