# Result of html5 Canvas getImageData or toDataURL - Which takes up more memory?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Part of my app includes html5 photo editing using a mixture of standard 2d context canvases and webGL.

Anyway, I am saving 'undo' states while the user is manipulating their photo.  These are all stored in a Javascript object as base64 image data.

Everything works fine and performance is good.

However I am wondering if storing the data from getImageData might take up less memory or offer better performance?

So to summarise my question is:

Which takes more space in memory, a base64 jpeg generated by toDataURL() or the result of getImageData()?  And are there any performance differences between the two (with regards to loading onto a canvas, and pulling the data off of a canvas)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good question! I'm not sure about the true sizes of the objects themselves, and it should differ between implementions of JS, but that doesn't mean we can't make some educated guesses.

First we can use the approximation function from this question: [JavaScript object size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size)

And make an example: http://jsfiddle.net/g39uz/

The string is perhaps 80116 bytes, compared to the ImageData's 720056 bytes. Or thereabouts.

There's an order of magnitude difference here, and the difference would be even more stark if the image was simple. It's worth remembering that the Base64 representation can be compressed (and it is). Let's take it to the limit for a moment to see, by using a blank canvas:

http://jsfiddle.net/g39uz/2/

On a blank canvas the dataURL string is just 1996 bytes (or thereabouts) but the image data, which of course still dutifully describes every single pixel in painstaking array detail, is still 720056.

In short, if you're storing it, the base64 string *probably* takes up less space. By an order of magnitude.

Comment: The tradeoff is the usual - for the massive amount of storage, you gain tons of processing time.  I just had a project where I was caching a single (roughly 600x500) image.  I did it first with toDataURL, and it was small - but setting new Image().src to the URL string dropped my framerate by a third.  In my case, it was worth the memory to improve the speed.

Answer (score 30):

**getImageData() takes more memory than toDataURL()**

- **ImageData** is pixel array, the largest information about image, the length of pixel array is `widthOfImage * heightOfImage * 4`, for example imageData length of image with dimensions 100 is `var imageDataArrayLenth = 100 * 100 * 4 = 40 000 (bytes);`
- **BLOB (JPG or PNG)** is imageData compressed with jpg or png algorithm can be less sized by 10 or 20 times than imageData (depends on image content).
- **DataURL (BASE64)** is imageData compressed to JPG or PNG, then converted to string, and this string is larger by 37% ([info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)) than BLOB.

Conclusion: Better way is to use **BLOB** ([info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)).

```
//Example of using blob with objectURL
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
  let img = new Image();
  img.onload = () =>  URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);  // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this the other day... the getImageData method returns an image object where the actual data is stored in a uint8array... you have to get the data converted to something your database can manage and its just not worth it, the final output is much larger than the toDataURL method

Its also very simple to get toDataURL base64 string back onto the canvas... you just instantiate a new image and give the src the base64 string