# How to measure memory usage of javascript object

Tags: javascript, canvas

for example i want to compare about "array of array of number" with "array of string" to store  bits of static canvas/image that has Alpha more or less than 0.5, that i will need to read/access it later

i wonder which one would have least memory usage and probably faster?

```
var c =$('$myCanvas');
var d = c[0].getContext('2d').getImageData().data; 
// access: d[3+4*(c.width()*y+x)] >= 0.5
```

vs

```
var n = [ [ 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], ... ]
// access: n[y][x/31|0] >> x%31 & 1
```

vs

```
var s = [ [ 255, 255, 255, 255, ... ].to_s(), [ 0, 0, 0, 0, ...].to_s(), ... ]
// access: n[y].charCodeAt(x/8|0) >> x%8 & 1
```

note that to_s() is custom function to convert array of byte to string similar to this one: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/pack-and-unpack-bytes-to-strings

those codes are probably wrong, it's just the concept that i will implement later

so, my question is, how to measure memory usage of d, n and s?

Comment: Very cool question, excited for an answer!

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the [V8 profiler](https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial). Playing with it's flags you can get the heap usage. Probably that's what you need.

Comment: this one? https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/V8Profiler
it doesn't show memory usage

Comment: I've done memory profiling using v8. I don't have experience with Spider Monkey.

Comment: But look here...probably if you build the engine with custom flags... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation