# adding functions to objects constructed from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, performance, oop

I have a collection of users which I just got from a JSON server response. Assume the following:

```
var users = [
    {id: 1, name: 'john', surname: 'smith'},
    {id: 2, name: 'john', surname: 'smith'},
    {id: 3, name: 'john', surname: 'smith'},
    {id: 4, name: 'john', surname: 'smith'},
    {id: 5, name: 'john', surname: 'smith'},
    {id: 6, name: 'john', surname: 'smith'},
    {id: 7, name: 'john', surname: 'smith'}
];
```

At some points in the business logic and the (handlebars) templates of the application I need to have the full name of each user but of course I don't want to repeat the concatenation logic of `name + ' ' + surname` all over the place.

Thus I do the following which "enhances" those users and adds this function I want:

```
for(var i=0,length=users.length; i<length; i++) {
    users[i].getFullName = function() {
        return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
    }
}
```

This technique works fine but my questions are:

- is there a better way of doing this? Note that I want an object oriented style solution and not something like `getFullNameOfUser(user)`.
- I can measure the time penalty to add the function to all those objects, but can I measure the memory penalty for adding the function to the objects? Solutions such as [JavaScript object size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1248302/72478) do not count functions.

Comment: `users[i].fullname = users[i].name + ' ' + users[i].surname` is not an option? :)

Comment: @Jack: No because this would cache the value. I want a live function/method on the object which can do anything with the state of the object.

Comment: Okay I was half kidding on that, but that was a point I had not considered :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could create a class, Users, and add getFullNameOfUser to the prototype.

```
var User = function(obj){
   this.id = obj.id;
   this.name = obj.name;
   this.surname = obj.surname;
};

User.prototype.getFullNameOfUser = function(){
   return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
};

for(var i=0,length=users.length; i<length; i++) {
    users[i] = new User(users[i]);
}
```

About your question in the comment, you could do:

```
var User = function(obj){
       for(var key in obj){
          this[key]  = obj[key];
       }
    };
```

but this way you might end up with unwanted properties in the object

Comment: This looks nice. Any idea on how to avoid manually copying all values from `obj` to `this` within the constructor?

Comment: Will `users[i].__proto__ = User.prototype` work as well?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Answer (score 0):

This seems inefficient because you are adding a function to each user.

Using handlebars.js you should be able to simply handle concatenation in the view, i.e.:

```
<h2>Welcome {{user.name}} {{user.surname}}!</h2>
```

Comment: The code was examplatory and simplified for the sake of the question. I'm doing more than just concatenation within those functions (e.g launching rockets).

Comment: Andre's answer is correct, creating a new class and creating JavaScript's version of a static method will prevent you from having to add a new function for each user.  Ideally you would create a list of User objects when loading the data so you don't double your memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a bunch of utility functions and call them with a specific context as needed.

```
function getFullName () {
   return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
};

getFullName.call(users[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I know but, as I mentioned, I wanted an OOP style solution.