# ScriptDB object size calculation

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to estimate the limits of my current GAS project. I use ScriptDB to chunk out processing to get around the 6 min execution limit. If I have an object like

```
var userObj{

   id: //user email address
   count: //integer 1-1000
   trigger: //trigger ID
   label: //string ~30 char or less
   folder: //Google Drive folder ID
   sendto: //'true' or 'false'
   shareto: //'true' or 'false'
}
```

How would I calculate the size that this object takes up in the DB? I would like to project how many of these objects can exist concurrently before I reach the 200MB limit for our domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you've got a question about google-apps-script that isn't about the API, try searching for javascript questions first. In this case, I found [JavaScript object size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size), and tried out the accepted answer in apps-script. (Actually, the "improved" accepted answer.) I've made no changes at all, but have reproduced it here with a test function so you can just cut & paste to try it out.

Here's what I got with the test `stud` object, in the debugger. [image: screenshot of debugger]

Now, it's not perfect - for instance, it doesn't factor in the size of the keys you'll use in ScriptDB. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6367736/1677912) took a stab at that. But since your object contains some potentially huge values, such as an email address which can be 256 characters long, the key lengths may be of little concern.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size/11900218#11900218
function roughSizeOfObject( object ) {

    var objectList = [];
    var stack = [ object ];
    var bytes = 0;

    while ( stack.length ) {
        var value = stack.pop();

        if ( typeof value === 'boolean' ) {
            bytes += 4;
        }
        else if ( typeof value === 'string' ) {
            bytes += value.length * 2;
        }
        else if ( typeof value === 'number' ) {
            bytes += 8;
        }
        else if
        (
            typeof value === 'object'
            && objectList.indexOf( value ) === -1
        )
        {
            objectList.push( value );

            for( i in value ) {
                stack.push( value[ i ] );
            }
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}


function Marks()
{
  this.maxMarks = 100;
}

function Student()
{
  this.firstName = "firstName";
  this.lastName = "lastName";
  this.marks = new Marks();
}

function test () {
  var stud = new Student();
  var studSize = roughSizeOfObject(stud);
  debugger;
}
```