# How to get Firebase Function request size?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**What is the best way to read size of a request object sent to Firebase Callable Function?**

I would like to take actions based on the size of request sent from a client but the only options I see are:

- calculating size of the object in a custom function as suggested [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900218/4841380)
- using the [object-sizeof](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-sizeof) npm package.

**Is there any build in Firebase solution to this?**

Comment: Normally you would use the headers in the HTTP request to find the size of the payload, but those are not exposed in callable functions.  You should file a feature request for that.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, I have filed a feature request. Are those exposed in Firebase HTTP Functions?

Comment: Yes, HTTP functions give you access to all the headers, just like you would expect from an Express app.