# Vuex profiling : How to know a vuex state or a component size in memory

Tags: vue.js, memory-management, vuex, memory-profiling

Is there a way to find **how much size** a state (object, array, etc) or a component occupies in memory.

In my current context, I need that to know if a specific state/component is very heavy (in term of memory).

In chrome, I already tried to snapshot the memory, but I couldn't find how to identify a specific component or state in the result in such large info like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For variables size you can find it using this [js function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900218/8847587) and then use console logs or using [google chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408593/8847587)

For component size check [Linus response](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-component-sizes/19888).

Comment: Thanks for answering but according to his answer `Quick & Dirty I would write something unique into the component’s data and search for that string.` , I will need to make too many manual changes then rollback. Not very interesting