# How to calculate the memory occupied by a variable in JavaScript？

Tags: javascript

How to calculate the memory occupied by a variable in JavaScript？
I want to know if there is an operation like `sizeof`.

Comment: as what I know it's **impossible** especially your variable's value is a complicated object, which its properties are in turn another objects

Comment: There's [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900218/9070080), which makes a rough estimate on the size of an object, but there is no inbuilt function that can do this