# How to find the memory of the javascript hasmap?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I'm using "npm i object-sizeof" to find the size character in a map.

```
var sizeof = require('object-sizeof')

const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('a', 'alpha');
map1.set('b', 'beta');
map1.set('g', 'gamma');

console.log(sizeof(map1.get('a')));
```

But i'm unable to get the value of console.log(sizeof(map1);
my aim is to get the size of character i.e key and value. Each character consist of 2 bytes.

Comment: on stack overflow the code are based on the length of the character but i need the memory size of the character.

Comment: check this answer I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900218/9501353