# what is the memory size of a weakmap object?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, weakmap

For example,
Suppose I have a weak map which links some dom element with another dom element like this:

```
let item1=document.querySelector("#item1");
let item2=document.querySelector("#item2");

const wMap = new WeakMap();
wMap.set(item1,item2);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900218/18005234) solution returns the byte value of the object
similarly, what would be the size of the weakmap in this case?

Comment: The size of 2 pointers + whatever overhead the JS engine adds.

Comment: @Keith could you elaborate on "overhead the JS engine adds"?

Comment: "*This solution returns the byte value of the object*" - no it doesn't, that's a very bad approximation. And it's not possible to get the size of a WeakMap.