# Is it possible to know how much memory a variable is taking in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on Frontend React and Javascript. I need to know, if there is a way to get the memory used by a javascript variable mostly for objects and non primitive values. I checked chrome dev tool, but couldn't find any option to get memory being used by a variable or constant.

Comment: I think you might find this usefull 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: Used JSProfiling,
 - Its in build chrome and firefox

If you want a detailed report then you can use **[Firebug][1]**

Firebug provides a highly detailed profiling report. 

  [1]: https://getfirebug.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. JavaScript hides all that from you.